# If I suppress my desires and refrain from homosexuality, will I get male spouses in paradise?

Tags: jannah, homosexuality

So I agree with everything about Islam and I can understand why gay marriage is not allowed. But if I live a good life and make it to Jannah, will Allah allow me to be in a homosexual relationship?

I keep hearing that Allah will remove homosexual desires out of my heart in Jannah... but I don't want that. I don't want to be brainwashed into liking women. Since it is not harmful to anyone like murder, and jealousy, and hatred... will Allah make it permissible in heaven just like he will make wearing silk and gold permissible for men in heaven?

Answer (score 6):

All people of heaven Allah will purify their hearts from psychological malice, bad morals, and despicable desires.

In fact, when you meet the Hoor Al Ayn in Jannah, you wont be looking around for men :')

Allah describes them in Surah Ar-Rahman ( Surah #55 ) verse #56:

فِيهِنَّ قَاصِرَاتُ الطَّرْفِ لَمْ يَطْمِثْهُنَّ إِنسٌ قَبْلَهُمْ وَلا جَانٌّ
In them are women limiting [their] glances, untouched before them by man or jinni

And in verse #58:

كَأَنَّهُنَّ الْيَاقُوتُ وَالْمَرْجَانُ
(In beauty) they are like rubies and coral

And also in verse #72:

حُورٌ مَّقْصُورَاتٌ فِي الْخِيَامِ
Fair ones reserved in pavilions

And in Surah Al-Baqarah ( Surah #2 ) verse #25:

وَبَشِّرِ الَّذِين آمَنُواْ وَعَمِلُواْ الصَّالِحَاتِ أَنَّ لَهُمْ جَنَّاتٍ تَجْرِي مِن تَحْتِهَا الأَنْهَارُ كُلَّمَا رُزِقُواْ مِنْهَا مِن ثَمَرَةٍ رِّزْقاً قَالُواْ هَـذَا الَّذِي رُزِقْنَا مِن قَبْلُ وَأُتُواْ بِهِ مُتَشَابِهاً وَلَهُمْ فِيهَا أَزْوَاجٌ مُّطَهَّرَةٌ وَهُمْ فِيهَا خَالِدُونَ
And give good tidings to those who believe and do righteous deeds that they will have gardens [in Paradise] beneath which rivers flow. Whenever they are provided with a provision of fruit therefrom, they will say, "This is what we were provided with before." And it is given to them in likeness. And they will have therein purified spouses, and they will abide therein eternally.

Every time you gaze upon her, you see nothing but that which gladdens the heart.

I believe the homosexual feeling you have now will fade away when you get to heaven inshallah.

And Allah knows the best.

Comment: I don't see how telling a gay man about attractive women is a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Basically whoever works and strives through the trials and tribulations of this world, does righteous deeds and earns themselves a place in Jannah, would certainly get whatever their heart desires. As I've heard a hadith where it said that in Jannah you shall get whatever your heart desires, and whatever you think and would love to have you shall have it.

That said, we should also note that sometimes although we may not get what we want in this world, like for instance a nice car. Even if someone longs for a car throughout the life in this world and doesnt get it, it doesn't necessarily mean that they would have the same wants in Jannah as well because in Jannah is something which no eye has ever seen and no heart has ever desired. So whether we would still want a Lamboghini in Jannah or not only Allah knows, but the bottomline is whatever we want, we shall get it.

Therefore our objective of this life is to enjoin the good, forbid the evil and believe in Allah and do righteous deeds. And Allah knows best

Comment: Please [add evidence for each claim in your answer](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/598/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question) and see [How do I add evidence to my answer?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3337/how-do-i-add-evidence-to-my-answer) for help with that.

Answer (score -1):

Can't be sure about that but what i can tell you is that ALLAH (SWT) said you will get whatever you desire in Haven so i think it shouldn't be a problem. But in Islam it is against human nature.

You should ask this question to a real Mufti or Aalim to get the authentic answer.

Answer (score -2):

there are two things that i can think of.

1. Medically, homosexuality is a sexual disorder occurring due to malfunctioning of brain's part responsible for sexual desires. It cannot be cured, because the reasons are unknown i. e. what causes it. As in Islam, it is mentioned that the people of paradise will have no disease, even the mad people would be just fine so perhaps this mental disorder is cured. As for not being brainwashed, what if you have no such memory of past left. how would you link your heterosexual behavior as altered from homosexuality? Have you seen Resident Evil in which the Alice wakes up with no memory of past. if your are like such, then at that point you will not consider yourself brainwashed as there would be no point of reference on which you could base that. In Sura Inam, Allah says, if we wanted everyone to be obedient, we could have done that. so if you are truly brainwashed, you would not have the ability to tell if you are.
2. there is a very specific ayat, perhaps some scholar will point, that says that in heaven you will have beautiful boys looking at them you find comfort and they will serve wine. does not say if you indulge in any activity or anything with them but if you are getting comfort looking at them then that may point to some minor homosexual behavior. though the Scholars disagree but at the very basic level it says exactly that. it does not say ladies (hoor)will serve as a heterosexual man will be more delighted to be served by woman rather than a beautiful boy. so it may be that you are not brainwashed but you get Male-hoors for you.

and now to a question i have. 
why are you so sure that you will go to heaven? what if you land in hell? have you considered your choices there?